# How to differentiate when user clicked on New or Save & New button in salesforce Lightning controller?

Tags: lightning, salesforce-id, button, save-and-new

I have overridden the standard new button using lightning component. In spite of this, when user is clicking on Save & New button on the edit screen, it is navigating the lightning component.

I don't want to navigate to lightning page when user clicks on save & New.
Is there any way to differentiate the standard New and Save & New button in lightning controller ?

Comment: please add lightning code snippet for better understanding